# numpy masked ragged array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to fill a masked array whose dtype is object (because I need to store masked ragged arrays) with a non scalar fill_value.

Here's an example of a 2D array whose elements are 1D numpy arrays. Of course, I would like the fill_value to be an empty array.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [np.arange(10), np.arange(5), np.arange(3)],
    [np.arange(1),  np.arange(2), np.array([])],
])

marr = np.ma.array(arr)

marr.mask = [[True, False, False],
             [True, False, True]]
marr.fill_value = np.array([])

marr.filled()
```

Unfortunately, it yields an error on the last line:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (2,3)
```

I could manually extract the mask, and apply it on an element-by-element algorithm; but it does not seem to be the right direction to me.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not count on `MaskedArray` to work well with object dtype arrays. `filled` is trying to copy the fill value, an array, into a subset of the slots in the `data`.  Due to broadcasting that can be tricky, even without the masking layer.

Look at the full error:

```
In [39]: marr.filled()                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-219e016a84cf> in <module>
----> 1 marr.filled()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py in filled(self, fill_value)
   3718             result = self._data.copy('K')
   3719             try:
-> 3720                 np.copyto(result, fill_value, where=m)
   3721             except (TypeError, AttributeError):
   3722                 fill_value = narray(fill_value, dtype=object)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (2,3)
```

`np.copyto` tries to broadcast `result`, `fill_value` and `m` (mask) against each other, and then copy the corresponding (mask==true) elements from `fill_value` to `result`.

`marr.data` and `marr.mask` are both `(2,3)`.  But broadcasting a (0,) shape to (2,3) doesn't work, and isn't what you want anyways.

Filling with a scalar works, but not with an array (or list).

```
In [56]: np.broadcast_to(np.array([]),(2,3))                                                                            
...
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (0,) and requested shape (2,3)
```

A (1,) shape array will broadcast -

```
In [57]: np.broadcast_to(np.array([1]),(2,3))                                                                           
Out[57]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

But the filled result is not an array; it's a scalar:

```
In [58]: marr.filled(np.array([1]))                                                                                     
Out[58]: 
array([[1, array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2])],
       [1, array([0, 1]), 1]], dtype=object)
```

### A fill that works

I can make this fill work if I define a (1,) object dtype array, and putting the (0,) array in it (as an object).

```
In [97]: Ofill = np.array([None], object)                                                                               
In [98]: Ofill[0] = np.array([])                                                                                        
In [99]: Ofill                                                                                                          
Out[99]: array([array([], dtype=float64)], dtype=object)
In [100]: marr.filled(Ofill)                                                                                            
Out[100]: 
array([[array([], dtype=float64), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
        array([0, 1, 2])],
       [array([], dtype=float64), array([0, 1]),
        array([], dtype=float64)]], dtype=object)
```

This works because `Ofill` can be broadcasted to (2,3) without messing with the shape of the element

```
In [101]: np.broadcast_to(Ofill,(2,3))                                                                                  
Out[101]: 
array([[array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64),
        array([], dtype=float64)],
       [array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64),
        array([], dtype=float64)]], dtype=object)
```

This works, but I wouldn't say it's pretty (or recommended).

Filling with `None` is prettier, but even then we have to make it a list:

```
In [103]: marr.filled([None])                                                                                           
Out[103]: 
array([[None, array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2])],
       [None, array([0, 1]), None]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function "filled" has be supplied with value to be filled for masked part.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([
    [np.arange(10), np.arange(5), np.arange(3)],
    [np.arange(1),  np.arange(2), np.array([])],
])
marr = np.ma.array(arr)
marr.mask = [[True, False, False],
             [True, False, True]]
marr.fill_value = np.array([])
marr.filled(2)
```

This version of code is not giving that error.

Comment: You are filling with a scalar, not the array that the OP is trying to use.

Comment: Something like `marr.filled(np.arange(1)) ` works, which replaces the element with array.

Comment: `filled` without argument uses the `fill_value`.